# How to turn off auto-capitalization in Excel VBA code editor

Tags: excel, vba

I've moved from Mac to Windows for some programming. And in my workbook I have a sheet named 'data'. But as I try to select this sheet using the code 'Sheets(data).Select', whenever I move my cursor of the word 'data' it will autocapitalize to 'Data'. It does this with all kinds of stuff and I simply cannot find a way to type the code with small letters.

I turned off all autocorrect options in Excel's options but without luck.

Comment: You probably want   'Sheets("data").Select' (quotes around data).

Comment: Visual Basic is not case sensitive like C# for example. For the language, 'Data' and 'data' is the same thing - it will capitalize or lower the case to match any previous declaration.

Answer (score 1):

To control how variables appear in your code, you should declare them. For example:

```
Dim data As Object
```

If you don't declare them and you initially type them with a capital letter, then the editor will remember this and use this format going forward. The only way I've found to overwrite this is to declare them.

Comment: That did the trick.
Nonetheless this is incredibly annoying because even with find-replace I could not get it to work and VBA insists on using the wrong code. I've not had this problem on my Mac, it would just register my key presses leaving me in control. Would still like to know how to turn this off completely.